# Does a C compiler provide any type definitions that have definite length?

Tags: c, types, linux-kernel, compilation

In the C language Specification, there are constraints of minimum length of built-in types; thus, a compiler must ensure that the length of `char` is at least 8 bit, `int` 32 bits, `long long` 64 bits, etc.

But, when I am implementing architecture-related parts of my kernel, I need some types that have *definite lengths* of 8 bits, 16 bits, 32 bits or 64 bits. With those types, I can read form or write to 8-bit and 16-bit I/O ports, or 32-bit and 64-bit registers. Are there any existing types that have assured lengths?

When I'm looking up such type definitions in Linux source code (like `u32` or `u64`), I found that they are defined by built-in types as:

```
<uapi\asm-generic\int-ll64.h>
typedef __signed__ char __s8;
typedef unsigned char __u8;
typedef __signed__ short __s16;
typedef unsigned short __u16;
typedef __signed__ int __s32;
typedef unsigned int __u32;
typedef __signed__ long long __s64;
typedef unsigned long long __u64;
```

and

```
<linu\asm-generic\int-ll64.h>
typedef __s8  s8;
typedef __u8  u8;
typedef __s16 s16;
typedef __u16 u16;
typedef __s32 s32;
typedef __u32 u32;
typedef __s64 s64;
typedef __u64 u64;
```

The kernel use such types to define some other types that look like they have definite length:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT
typedef u64 phys_addr_t;
#else
typedef u32 phys_addr_t;
#endif
```

Or to say, when compiling code for specific architecture, lengths of those built-in types can be assured? Or does the Linux MakeFile use some flags and compile options to make type lengths fixed?

Comment: Look at **stdint.h** for standard-width types. The definitions of these boils down to the built-in primitives, but those are compiler- and platform-dependent. It's not a problem, since each compiler + platform config provides its own standard header to guarantee the correct data sizes. You should avoid using types that have `__` prefixes, as they are internal to the implementation.

Comment: *"In the C language Specification, there are constraints of minimum length of built-in types; thus, a compiler must ensure that the length of char is at least 8 bit, int 32 bits ..."* `int` can be 16 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C Standard specifies the "stdint.h" header/library file (which you can incorporate into your code with a line like `#include <stdint.h>`) that provdes definitions for 'fixed width' integer types.

From [this Draft C11 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 7.20 Integer types `<stdint.h>`
>
> 1      The header `<stdint.h>` declares sets of
> integer types having specified widths, and defines corresponding sets
> of macros. It also defines macros that specify limits of integer
> types corresponding to types defined in other standard headers.

Using this header, you have access to types like `int64_t` and `uint8_t`; from the same Draft Standard section (bold italic emphasis in §3 mine):

> ##### 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>
> 1      The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed
> integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a two’s complement
> representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed integer type with a
> width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> 2      The typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned
> integer type with width N, no padding bits, Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> 3      These types are ***optional***. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it ***shall define*** the corresponding typedef names.

---

Note: This "stdint.h" header is also specified in the same section of the [C17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) and in a similar one (§7.22) in [C23](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf). It has been part of the Standard since at least [C99](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (§7.18).

Comment: You can find various publications and drafts [here](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/projects#9899), including the N1570 draft you linked.

Comment: @Adrian Mole
(Sorry for typo of compile option, here correct it by repost a new one.) So even if I use `-nostdinc` and `-nostdlib` options, the only thing I need to do is copy the local(or to say the platform on which I'm building my project) 'stdint.h' to my project and use those types, then compiler will do everything correctly?

Comment: Well, I'm not a GNU user but, from what I can see, the `-nostdinc` would appear to prevent the compiler from seeing the Standard include files ... which won't work. However, that file will still *exist* on your system, and you can copy it and/or extract the relevant `typedef` aliases therefrom and put those into your own header.

Comment: @08822407d `stdint.h` is a mandatory header available on every C compiler released during the past 25 years or so. You never muck around with standard headers by manually copying them, that's not how compiler libraries work. You wouldn't even do that on bare metal microcontroller system.